# Database structure - How to link users to jobs?

Tags: sql, database, database-design

I'm starting a project where people can sign up, login to their account and search for jobs base don their location and industry etc.

These are the tables I have identified I will need so far, however, I want each user to be able to apply for a job and keep track as to what jobs they have applied for.

For example, they click an 'apply' button on a job and it adds that specific job their account somewhere which will then allow me to run a query along the lines of "SELECT * jobs WHERE (this user has applied)".

**tblUser:**
-userID
-firstname
-surname
-dob
-email
-address

**tblJob**
-jobID
-Title
-Description
-Position *(full time/part time)*
-Salary
-DatePosted
***-userID???? <--as FK?***
-LocationID
-industryID

**tblIndustry**
-IndustryID
-IndustryName

**tblLocation**
-LocationID
-LocationName

Would this be correct and work? Also, are there any suggestions on any extra functionality I could add?

Answer (score 1):

you need a new table

```
user_applications
-----------------
user_id
job_id
application_dt
status
```

something like that.
do not put he user id directly in the job table as you have shown.

Answer (score 1):

You would probably want a table `tblJobApplications` with foreign keys to `tblUser` and `tblJob` tables.

You would query on it like

```
SELECT * {or pick your specific fields here}
FROM tblJobApplications AS ja
INNER JOIN tblJob AS j ON ja.job_id = j.job_id
WHERE ja.user_id = ?
```

Answer (score 1):

You need a relation of the type many to many, so just create a new table that will have the id from the job and the id from the user. Also, you need to make both primary keys.

EDIT:

Each time somebody applies to a job you insert in that table both the job's id and the user's id.